# Room returns list with one item instead of empty list when running count() with an inner join query

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I ran this query

```
 SELECT SURVEY.* 
      , COUNT(RESPONSE.OFFLINE_ID) AS responseCount 
   FROM SURVEY 
        INNER JOIN RESPONSE 
                ON SURVEY.OFFLINE_ID = RESPONSE.OFFLINE_SURVEY_ID
```

on an empty database and I got a list with one object that has all fields set to null and the count field set to 0 instead of an empty list. Can someone please help with a fix for this?

**UPDATE:**
For better clarity due to my poor column naming;

- The relationship between SURVEY and RESPONSE is one-to-many.
- SURVEY Primary key is OFFLINE_ID
- RESPONSE Primary key is OFFLINE_ID
- Foreign key identifier for SURVEY in RESPONSE table is
  OFFLINE_SURVEY_ID.

What I'm simply trying to do is fetch a list of Surveys along with the corresponding response count.

Comment: What are you expecting back? It's an empty database. You shouldn't expect anything back.

Comment: What happens if you add `GROUP BY SURVEY.*` to the end of the query?

Comment: That sounds right. Using an aggregate function like `count()` and also including non-grouped columns in the output is an error in most databases, btw, but sqlite will pick a random row from the results (if any) to use for those values. There are no rows, so null is used instead.

Comment: @JD333 I was expecting an empty list. But it returns a non-empty list with one item

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem That returns an empty list as expected but also returns an empty list when there are surveys having no responses

Comment: @Shawn I guess that's a mistake on my part. Thanks.

Comment: Just changed it to a left join and it works perfectly with the group. Thanks @all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you describe is quite amazing, since I can see no way the query in your question would run on any standard SQL system. The code as it is in your question should have the server complain about a missing GROUP BY, however looks like sqlite is an exception, as per @Shawn 's comment...

---

So, assuming:

1. above, and
2. that you want  an empty list for empty db as a result, and
3. that there is an ID column in SURVEY,

the following query may be what you want:

```
SELECT
    SURVEY.* , 
    COUNT(RESPONSE.OFFLINE_ID) AS responseCount
FROM
    SURVEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    RESPONSE
ON
    SURVEY.OFFLINE_ID = RESPONSE.OFFLINE_SURVEY_ID 
GROUP BY
    SURVEY.OFFLINE_ID;
```

Comment: See my comment on the question for why it doesn't give an error.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `HAVING` since this is an inner join.

Comment: Please see updated question. This doesn't work when Survey table has data but Response table is empty

Comment: What I needed was a left join with your answer, excluding the "HAVING". Thanks. You can edit your answer so I can mark as accepted

Comment: OK, Thanks! I will do that.